# Possible improvement for badges would like your thoughts

Tags: feature-request, badges, help

At the moment the badges page lists the names of the badges and a one sentence explanation of the badges. This is often ambiguous and I for one have been awarded badges when I did not expect it (just happened again) and not been awarded then when I though I ought to have (like the day I voted on 40 posts and still did not get a Vox Populi for some reason). Is this only me or has this happened to others?

As a possible remedy to the ambiguity could we create a more information link on the badges pages. I would be happy to get started writing the content if someone in the community knows how to make the links on the badges page. I just wanted to know everyone's thoughts on the idea and if anyone knows how we could make this a reality if enough people are interested. Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: Is this faq what you're looking for? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions

Comment: As for the Vox Populi, probably one (or more) of the posts you voted on was deleted before the end of the day, thus your vote vanished with it.

Comment: Yes @mat but I want to link it to the badges page.